# $_POST levar o <form name="este nome"...>

Tags: php, html

Tenho dois forms submetendo pro mesmo arquivo e preciso fazer um if() pra verificar qual algoritmo deverá ser executado, mas o $_POST não leva o nome do form apenas os valores.

```
<form name="frmCadastro" method="post" action="../_controllers/ccontatos.php">

<form name="frmGrupos" method="post" action="../_controllers/ccontatos.php">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um campo do tipo *hidden* para identificar qual formulário está sendo submetido.

No HTML:

```
<form name="frmCadastro" method="post" action="../_controllers/ccontatos.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="cadastro" />
</form>

<form name="frmGrupos" method="post" action="../_controllers/ccontatos.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="grupos" />
</form>
```

No PHP:

```
if ($_POST['form_name'] == 'cadastro') {
  // formulário cadastro
} else if ($_POST['form_name'] == 'grupos') {
  // formulário grupos
}
```

Comment: entendi, é uma boa alternativa mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado. :)